# How to provide Security in google cloud endpoints?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have used the various ways of accessing endpoints and securing by using the API key or token.
The above approach needs to specify the token or API in Header or URI respectively.
Is there any way that we allow the access to cloud endpoints securely to specific users without providing the token or API key

Answer (score 1):

No. API key and token are the only ways to secure a Google Cloud Endpoint.

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method

Comment: Can we do it without passing token or API key  through the URL or Header

Comment: How else would it work? You need the auth token to identify the specific user, so the auth token must be passed.

Comment: I dont want any other client or auth token, i want to do it like providing the specific ip in cloud armor and only those ip could access the cloud endpoints but as of now cloud armor does not provide this functionality, so is there any similar way for this